# Why do some electric circuts need 2 or more voltage sources

Tags: source

Why would we put 2 voltage sources(bateries) into an electric circut  ?
What are some real world examples where they are needed ?

Comment: Dual supply devices, extra voltage to drive motors solenoids LEDs etc, there are many reasons.

Comment: Also if you mean 1.5V AA or AAA battery - their voltage is too low. There could be a million reasons. The question is too broad.

Comment: My guess on this question: I have seen devices that require (say) 4 C cells and 3 AA cells - the C cells are supplying 6 volts to current-hungry devices such as motors while the AA cells are supplying 3 volts to low-current logic circuits. The manufacturer could have added a DC-to-DC to supply the logic didn’t to greatly reduce the manufacturing cost. This also provides very clean voltage to the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is too broad. One example is: if you have a simple circuit with one battery and one load, you can add one more battery in series to deliver more power to the load. If your load needs 3 V, you can put two 1.5 V batteries in series to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Actually one is enough. If the system has several subsystems which are most economically produced using different operating voltages, we can produce from one voltage the rest of the voltages with converters. The converter can well be more economical and comfortable, too, than several separate sources.

An example. A sound system needs 50VDC to give the wanted power to the used high power speakers. The preamp has been built using parts that need 12VDC. We probably make that 12V by adding a voltage dropping regulator.

In the era before mass produced semiconductor components people had portable equipment such as radios which contained electron tubes. They needed say 100VDC for anode circuits (less wasn't enough to rip the electrons out of the cathodes) and say 2VDC to heaten the cathodes enough to make 100V to be enough to make the current to flow. 2V battery was designed for long time high current. 100V battery was desighed for smaller current, but much higher voltage. The pure economy forced to make them separate, altoug in theory 100V battery could give also the heater current - only a series resistor must be added.

I have made a dual channel optocoupled oscilloscope preamp for tracing where the interfering pulses come. I wanted to remove all possible connections between the oscilloscope and the channel inputs. Both preamps got their own 9 volt battery.

In many systems AC voltages are the natural signal type. It's economical to handle them with symmetrical circuits which have one half for the positive voltages and one half for the negative voltages. Transistors unfortunately do not cope with both polarities, so each polarity needs separate transistors. Those circuit halves most easily also have opposite operating voltages. This is very common design pribciple. Another way is to add so much DC that only one polarity is needed and finally filter the DC out. That's not allways economical, altough often possible.